# xmlns = "" disappears when parsing over xml file

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree, xml-namespaces

I am parsing over an xml file that looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--WFVersion:53.0-->
<Tag1 xmlns="http:www.intel.com/example">
  <Tag2 attrib1="100"
    attrib2="400000"
        xmlns="" />
```

I need to change one of the attributes in the file while preserving the empty xml namespace attribute (xmlns = "").
Currently, I'm using

```
ET.register_namespace("", "http:www.intel.com/example")
```

to preserve the non-empty xml namespace.

Overall my code looks like this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = ET.parse(file_path)
ET.register_namespace("", "http:www.intel.com/example")
#change something
with open(workflow_path, 'w+') as f: 
    f.write(ET.tostring(xml.getroot()).decode())
```

And the problem is that the writing action removes empty xml namespaces (even without making any changes in the xml)

Comment: Why not to use XSLT for the task?

Comment: It is the etree library that is causing issues.  Why are you converting the xml to a string when you are using an xml library?

Comment: @jdweng I get the same issue when I use xml.write instead of writing with tostring

Comment: Seems like an ElementTree bug. Are you able to use lxml instead? It seems to work fine if you don't register the `http:www.intel.com/example` default namespace.

Comment: Why are you appending  to an existing file using w+.  All you need to do is to xml.Write('filename').  you are using an xml library. When you change something the document also changes.

Comment: @DanielHaley if I don't register the default namespace, the prefix "ns0" is added before Tag1 in the result xml file

Comment: @jdweng I get the same issue when I use xml.write

Comment: The namespace is not needed since it is the same as the parent.  The library is just removing unneeded code.

Comment: @jdweng - It's not in the same namespace as the parent. The parent is `{http:www.intel.com/example}Tag1` and the element with the empty ns is `{}Tag2`.

Comment: @Sandra - With lxml? See my answer for an example of not registering the namespace using lxml.

Comment: @DanielHaley : The OP only post pieces of the XML and said "looks something like this".  The OP doesn't know XML as well as we do an may not of posted important sections of the xml.

Comment: Yes, it seems like a bug in ElementTree. An "undeclaration" should not be discarded (see http://www.rpbourret.com/xml/NamespacesFAQ.htm#decl_8).

Answer (score 0):

If you can use lxml, the following seems to work...

**XML input** (scratch_22.xml)

```xml
<!--WFVersion:53.0-->
<Tag1 xmlns="http:www.intel.com/example">
  <Tag2 attrib1="100"
    attrib2="400000"
        xmlns="" />
</Tag1>
```

**Python**

```py
from lxml import etree

xml = etree.parse("scratch_22.xml")

tag2 = xml.find("Tag2")
tag2.set("attrib1", "i was changed")

etree.dump(xml.getroot())
```

**Output** (dumped to console, but .write() also works)

```xml
<Tag1 xmlns="http:www.intel.com/example">
  <Tag2 xmlns="" attrib1="i was changed" attrib2="400000"/>
</Tag1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one with xml.etree.ElementTree as a workaround:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from io import StringIO

xmlstr = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--WFVersion:53.0-->
<Tag1 xmlns="http://www.intel.com/example">
  <Tag2 attrib1="100"
    attrib2="400000"
        xmlns="" />
</Tag1>"""
f = StringIO(xmlstr)

tree = ET.parse(f)
root = tree.getroot()
ET.dump(root)

ET.register_namespace("", "http://www.intel.com/example")
Tag2 = root.find("Tag2")
Tag2.set('xmlns', "")

#change something
tree.write('namespace.xml', xml_declaration=True, encoding="UTF-8")
ET.dump(tree)
```

The dumps:

```
<Tag1 xmlns="http://www.intel.com/example">
  <Tag2 attrib1="100" attrib2="400000" />
</Tag1>
<Tag1 xmlns="http://www.intel.com/example">
  <Tag2 attrib1="100" attrib2="400000" xmlns="" />
</Tag1>
```

Output file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Tag1 xmlns="http://www.intel.com/example">
  <Tag2 attrib1="100" attrib2="400000" xmlns="" />
</Tag1>
```

Comment: This does not preserve `xmlns=""`.

Comment: @mzjn Thanks now I get your point and updated my answer.

Comment: OK, but this is not a general solution since it preserves `xmlns=""` in a special case only (on the `Tag2` element). `xmlns=""` might occur on any element.